# Adding records to mapping table in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I have following structure in EF for Users.

- Users - This will hold all the users (Standard as well as Supervisor Users).
- Supervisors - This will hold only Supervisors
- UserToSupervisors - This will hold mapping of both. A supervisor can have multiple standard members.

Now if new supervisor is added. i first add it to the Supervisor table, and then in the UserToSupervisor table with navigational properties like below.

```
userDo.Supervisor = new Supervisor { Id = userDo.Id, Type = "GROUP LEADER" };
```

Then i add it to the mapping table like below:

```
userDo.Supervisor.UserToSupervisors.Add(new UserToSupervisor
{
   UserId = userDo.Id,
   SupervisorId =  GetSelectedGroupLeaderId
});
```

and finally i call `userDao.Add(userDo)`

Now on Saving changes to database, the user is created, also supervisor is fine. However in UserToSupervisor table it adds UserId and `SupervisorId` both of the Current user, although it should add `SupervisorId` of the Supervisor from `GetSelectedGroupLeaderId`.

During Debugging i verified the `GetSelectedGroupLeaderId` is populated with proper `SupervisorId`.

But during SaveChanges call, it changes to current userid. I doubt that's because i am first calling userDo.Supervisor and assinging current user. but that's required since the current user is a supervisor user and not standard user.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with my above code?

Comment: when I was a very young gentleman, the design of user-supervisor was as follow: since the supervisor is also a user, the user table had a column `super` where you would put the `id` -- `userId, superId, isSuper`. Bob:`1, null, 1`; Charlie:`2, 1, 0`

Comment: Yes i used to do that, but once my senior told me, this is not the proper approach, we should break down the redundency and separate the mapping table.